# Updating Items In A Shopping Cart With Django

Tags: python, django

I am tracking the total cost of items in a shopping cart with Django. My problem is the first item is tracked. When you deduct quantity or reduce quantity the price adjust. But anything that is below it does NOT adjust the total cost. I think the problem is I am not looping through it incorrectly so after many hours of failure I figured I would ask.

In

```
def cart()
```

I am looping through the member variables add updating 
their values. The problem I am facing is that only the `book_id` is being passed to the `cart()` function when you click `remove_from_cart`

But if it was a problem of only one `book_id` being passed in then how come only the first item in the cart list is being changed regardless of the `book_id` that is being passed in?

views.py

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request,book_id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)
    cart,created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, active=True)
    order,created = BookOrder.objects.get_or_create(book=book,cart=cart)
    order.quantity += 1
    order.save()
    messages.success(request, "Cart updated!")
    return redirect('cart')


def remove_from_cart(request, book_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        try:
            book = Book.objects.get(pk = book_id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass 
        else:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(user = request.user, active = True)
            cart.remove_from_cart(book_id)
        return redirect('cart')
    else:
        return redirect('index')


def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, active = True)
        orders = BookOrder.objects.filter(cart=cart)
        total = 0
        count = 0
        for order in orders:
            total += order.book.price * order.quantity
            count += order.quantity
            context = {
            'cart': orders,
            'total': total,
            'count': count,
            }
            return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
        else:
            return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is slightly off

```
def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, active = True)
        orders = BookOrder.objects.filter(cart=cart)
        total = 0
        count = 0
        for order in orders:
            total += order.book.price * order.quantity
            count += order.quantity
        #Indentation needs to be offset by one level from here on
        context = {
            'cart': orders,
            'total': total,
            'count': count,
        }
        return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

Comment: omg... You are such a boss. This caused me hours and hours of grief. How can my linter not catch this? How can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: These are unfortunately caught only by logically understanding the flow. To debug, one way to go about is using print statements, or using `pdb` ...